# Spring kafka message consumer delay

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using Spring kafka 1.0.3 to consumer kafka message. 2 Topics in kafka and each topic has 1 partition. 
In java code, there is 2 @KafkaListener to consumer each topic message. The concurrency of ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory is set to 1. But messages sometimes delay 20+ seconds.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

@Value("${kafka.brokers}")
private String brokers;

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>>
kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(1);
  factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL);
    return factory;
}


@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
}

@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "server-group");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
    return props;
}
```

@KafkaListenr code is below:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "serverInChannel",topics =   CommonContants.KAFKA_TOPIC.SERVER_IN_CHANNEL)
public void consumeInMessage(@Payload String data,
                                 @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                              @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) String partitionId,
                              Acknowledgment ack) {
    logger.info("[serverInMessage]data=" + data);
    ack.acknowledge();
}

@KafkaListener(id = "webOutChannel",topics = CommonContants.KAFKA_TOPIC.WEB_OUT_CHANNEL)
public void consumeOutMessage(@Payload String data,
                               @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) String partitionId,
                               Acknowledgment ack) {
    logger.info("[webOutMessage]data=" + data);
    ack.acknowledge();
}
```

The kafka message is send by spring kafka , and logs is here:

```
2016-09-26 16:16:42,777 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-listener-4] [INFO] c.x.u.n.s.l.MessageListener - [serverInMessage]data=123abc
2016-09-26 16:16:44,101 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-listener-6] [INFO] c.x.u.n.s.l.MessageListener - [webOutMessage]data=123abc
2016-09-26 16:16:45,551 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked:[web_message_out_channel-0]
2016-09-26 16:16:45,562 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-listener-4] [INFO] c.x.u.n.s.l.MessageListener - [serverInMessage]data=123abc
2016-09-26 16:16:45,663 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked:[server_message_in_channel-0]
2016-09-26 16:16:45,715 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions assigned:[]
2016-09-26 16:16:45,781 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions assigned:[web_message_out_channel-0]
2016-09-26 16:16:45,805 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-listener-7] [INFO] c.x.u.n.s.l.MessageListener - [webOutMessage]data=123abc
2016-09-26 16:16:45,870 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-listener-7] [INFO] c.x.u.n.s.l.MessageListener - [webOutMessage]data=123abc
2016-09-26 16:17:01,099 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked:[]
2016-09-26 16:17:02,054 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked:[web_message_out_channel-0]
2016-09-26 16:17:02,108 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions assigned:[web_message_out_channel-0]
2016-09-26 16:17:02,120 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions assigned:[server_message_in_channel-0]
2016-09-26 16:17:02,133 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-listener-5] [INFO] c.x.u.n.s.l.MessageListener - [serverInMessage]data=123abc
```

There is some `partitions assigned:[]` in the logs, I do not know why assigned is empty. And after webOutMessage message was consume at `2016-09-26 16:16:45,870`, the next action was consumer rebalance after 15+ seconds at `2016-09-26 16:17:01,099`, so the next message was delay in 15+ seconds.

Is anybody know why?

Add debug logs, and delay is not everytime, sometimes is ok：

```
2016-09-27 15:33:58,329 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-listener-2] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.a.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=123abc, headers={kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=1234567890-1474961636372, kafka_offset=179, kafka_receivedTopic=server_message_in_channel, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = server_message_in_channel, partition = 0, offset = 179, key = 1234567890-1474961636372, value = 123abc)}]]
2016-09-27 15:33:58,329 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-listener-2] [INFO] c.x.u.n.s.l.MessageListener - [serverInMessage]data=123abc
2016-09-27 15:33:58,329 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {server_message_in_channel-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=180, metadata=''}}
2016-09-27 15:33:58,329 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Committing: {server_message_in_channel-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=180, metadata=''}}
2016-09-27 15:33:58,623 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Stopping invoker
2016-09-27 15:33:58,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Stopping invoker
2016-09-27 15:33:59,248 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Invoker stopped
2016-09-27 15:33:59,248 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:33:59,248 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked:[web_message_out_channel-0]
2016-09-27 15:33:59,330 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Invoker stopped
2016-09-27 15:33:59,330 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:33:59,330 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked:[server_message_in_channel-0]
2016-09-27 15:33:59,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Committing: {}
2016-09-27 15:33:59,405 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Committing: {}
2016-09-27 15:33:59,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions assigned:[]
2016-09-27 15:33:59,405 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions assigned:[]
2016-09-27 15:33:59,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:33:59,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:33:59,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:33:59,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:00,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:00,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:00,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:00,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:01,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:01,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:01,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:01,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:02,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:02,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:02,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:02,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:03,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:03,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:03,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:03,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:04,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:04,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:04,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:04,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:05,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:05,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:05,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:05,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:06,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:06,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:06,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:06,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:07,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:07,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:07,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:07,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:08,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:08,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:08,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:08,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:09,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:09,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:09,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:09,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:10,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:10,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:10,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:10,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:11,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:11,405 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:11,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:11,624 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:12,406 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:12,406 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:12,626 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:12,626 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:13,406 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:13,406 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:13,626 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:13,626 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:14,406 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:14,406 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:14,599 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked:[]
2016-09-27 15:34:14,599 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked:[]
2016-09-27 15:34:15,276 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Committing: {web_message_out_channel-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=174, metadata=''}}
2016-09-27 15:34:15,286 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Committing: {server_message_in_channel-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=180, metadata=''}}
2016-09-27 15:34:15,516 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions assigned:[server_message_in_channel-0]
2016-09-27 15:34:15,516 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [INFO] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions assigned:[web_message_out_channel-0]
2016-09-27 15:34:15,518 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:15,518 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:15,518 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 0 records
2016-09-27 15:34:15,518 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:15,787 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 3 records
2016-09-27 15:34:15,787 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:15,792 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-listener-4] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.a.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=123abc, headers={kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=1234567890-1474961636372, kafka_offset=174, kafka_receivedTopic=web_message_out_channel, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = web_message_out_channel, partition = 0, offset = 174, key = 1234567890-1474961636372, value = 123abc)}]]
2016-09-27 15:34:15,792 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-listener-4] [INFO] c.x.u.n.s.l.MessageListener - [webOutMessage]data=123abc
2016-09-27 15:34:15,792 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-listener-4] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.a.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=123abc, headers={kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=1234567890-1474961636372, kafka_offset=175, kafka_receivedTopic=web_message_out_channel, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = web_message_out_channel, partition = 0, offset = 175, key = 1234567890-1474961636372, value = 123abc)}]]
2016-09-27 15:34:15,793 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-listener-4] [INFO] c.x.u.n.s.l.MessageListener - [webOutMessage]data=123abc
2016-09-27 15:34:15,793 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-listener-4] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.a.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=123abc, headers={kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=1234567890-1474961636372, kafka_offset=176, kafka_receivedTopic=web_message_out_channel, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = web_message_out_channel, partition = 0, offset = 176, key = 1234567890-1474961636372, value = 123abc)}]]
2016-09-27 15:34:15,793 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-listener-4] [INFO] c.x.u.n.s.l.MessageListener - [webOutMessage]data=123abc
2016-09-27 15:34:15,794 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {web_message_out_channel-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=177, metadata=''}}
2016-09-27 15:34:15,794 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Committing: {web_message_out_channel-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=177, metadata=''}}
2016-09-27 15:34:15,795 [webOutChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Woken up during commit
2016-09-27 15:34:15,796 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Received: 2 records
2016-09-27 15:34:15,805 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {}
2016-09-27 15:34:15,805 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-listener-3] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.a.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=123abc, headers={kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=1234567890-1474961636372, kafka_offset=180, kafka_receivedTopic=server_message_in_channel, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = server_message_in_channel, partition = 0, offset = 180, key = 1234567890-1474961636372, value = 123abc)}]]
2016-09-27 15:34:15,805 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-listener-3] [INFO] c.x.u.n.s.l.MessageListener - [serverInMessage]data=123abc
2016-09-27 15:34:15,806 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-listener-3] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.a.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=123abc, headers={kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=1234567890-1474961636372, kafka_offset=181, kafka_receivedTopic=server_message_in_channel, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = server_message_in_channel, partition = 0, offset = 181, key = 1234567890-1474961636372, value = 123abc)}]]
2016-09-27 15:34:15,806 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-listener-3] [INFO] c.x.u.n.s.l.MessageListener - [serverInMessage]data=123abc
2016-09-27 15:34:15,808 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Commit list: {server_message_in_channel-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=182, metadata=''}}
2016-09-27 15:34:15,808 [serverInChannel-0-kafka-consumer-1] [DEBUG] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Committing: {server_message_in_channel-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=182, metadata=''}}
```

Comment: Enable DEBUG logging for o.s.kafka and o.a.k.clients to see if it provides more information.

Comment: add some debug logs at end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The container is properly reacting to a partition rebalance initiated by the broker.

You would have to examine the server logs to determine what would be the cause of that rebalance.